# Почему выдает ошибку? aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Консоль выдает вот это (в нижней кнопке 'klav') :

```
raise NameError("Invalid filter name(s): '" + "', ".join(full_config.keys()) + "'")
NameError: Invalid filter name(s): 'message'
```

Из-за чего это может быть???

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

api_token = 'TOKEN'

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token = api_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    buttons = ["Начать", "Помощь"]
    keyboard.add(*buttons)
    await message.answer("Выберите", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.message_handler(message = 'Начать')
async def promo(message: types.Message):
    klav = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buttonA = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'da')
    buttonB = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'да')
    klav.add(buttonA, buttonB)
    await message.answer('Выберите', reply_markup=klav)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling (dp, skip_updates = True)
```

Comment: `@dp.message_handler(message = 'Начать')` А разве у него есть параметр `message`? https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/index.html#aiogram.Dispatcher.message_handler

Comment: Благодарю, я совсем забыл про документацию

Comment: Так удалите вопрос. Он больше не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Вместо
`@dp.message_handler(message = 'Начать' )`
сделайте
`text='Начать'`
И в инлайн кнопки добавте `callback_data="main:yes"`
и в другой так само
И
`klav.add(*<список ваших кнопок>)`

Answer (score 0):

`message` нет в библиотеке aiogram.

Замени строку

```
@dp.message_handler(message = 'Начать')
```

На

```
@dp.message_handler(text = 'Начать')
```